# Listen to redis expiration events of specific key names

Tags: redis

I have a node.js code that listen to redis key expiration events:

```
const subscriber = require('redis').createClient(port, host);

subscriber.subscribe('__keyevent@0__:expired');

subscriber.on('message', async (channel, key) => {
    // do somenthing
}
```

But I want to listen to expiration events of specific key name pattern. Example: I want to listen events when keys like "foo_bar_123" and "foo_bar_456" ("foo_bar_*") expire.

Is there a way to achieve this by changing "__keyevent@0__:expired""?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can listen to the key-space notification:

```
config set notify-keyspace-events Kx
```

Then subscribe with a key pattern:

```
psubscribe __keyspace@0__:foo_bar_*
```

When *foo_bar_1* expires, you'll get the corresponding message:

```
1) "pmessage"
2) "__keyspace@0__:foo_bar_*"
3) "__keyspace@0__:foo_bar_1"
4) "expired"
```

Comment: I couldn't get foo_bar_* event; I could only get event if I use entire key name "\_\_keyspace@0\_\_:foo_bar_123"; it seems that * doesn't work

Comment: @Danilo You should use **psubscribe**, NOT *subscribe*. **P** stands for pattern.

Comment: I could not get the event either

Comment: Is there a way to receive only expired events for a specific key?

Comment: @gemr1423 AFAIK, NO, you cannot do that.

Comment: Is there a way to get the expired key and not only the `expired` message?

Comment: @EliZatlawy You need to listen to the  Key-event notification: `subscribe __keyevent@0__:expire`